# How to get selected text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getselection

I'm a little confused why doesn't this code work!

The HTML Markup:

```
<div id="diva"><b>Score</b> some <i>goals</i></div>
<div id="soda"></div>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
function GetSelectedText () {
if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    var range = window.getSelection ();
    alert (range.toString ());
} 
else {
    if (document.selection.createRange) { // Internet Explorer
        var range = document.selection.createRange ();
        alert (range.text);
    }
}
}

var butn = document.getElementById("soda");
butn.onclick = function(){
    GetSelectedText();
}
```

Comment: It's usually better if you explain what is actually happening rather than saying "_this code doesn't work_".  I'd receommend looking into [the jQuery Caret plugin](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php)

Comment: If you click on anything while a piece of text is highlighted, doesn't that unhighlight it and leave your selection blank?

Comment: you have a space after your toString and other functions - but we need more detail, are you seeing an error or just the wrong behavior?

Comment: jahroy is right. Use a proper library, jQuery being warmly recommended here. Otherwise, you'll be spending your time learning how the different browsers handle selection.

Comment: @MihaiDanila: A "proper library" will be no help here. The problem is that in some browsers, by the time the button's `click` event fires, the selection has been destroyed.

Comment: @danronmoon: In general yes, but it doesn't happen with actual `<button>` and `<input type="button">` elements.

Comment: "When in doubt throw libraries at it otherwise you might have to learn! Scary thought.."

Comment: I mean by saying "doesn't work" that it doesn't do what I'm expecting which is to give me the selected text in HTML format. So when I select "Some" I expect to have this in the alert popup "<b>Score</b>"

Sorry if my question was unclear!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One problem that you may well be experiencing is that in some browsers (notably IE), by the time the button's `click` event fires, the selection has been destroyed. You can fix this by using the `mousedown` event instead (which still allows the selection to be destroyed, but only after the event has been handled), or by [making the button unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#4358620).

I assume your button is not an actual button input, because this behaviour only happens for regular elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L9bvU/1/

```js
function GetSelectedText () {
    if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
        var range = window.getSelection ();
        alert (range.toString ());
    } 
    else {
        if (document.selection.createRange) { // Internet Explorer
            var range = document.selection.createRange ();
            alert (range.text);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
span {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    
}

*[unselectable="on"] {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Please select some of this text and press a button below</div>

<span onclick="GetSelectedText()">Click</span>
<span onmousedown="GetSelectedText()">Mousedown</span>
<span unselectable="on" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Click, unselectable</span>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but I have another problem which is why I want this code to do.

I'm expecting which is to give me the selected text in HTML format. So when I select "Some" I expect to have this in the alert popup "<b>Score</b>" Sorry if my question was unclear!

Comment: I have found this code and it is very useful but it doesn't work and I don't know why. In the other hand I replaced the "alert (range.text);"  with "alert (range.htmlText);" and it works very will in IE but I need the equivalent code to the rest of the browsers, I mean to say "what to replace "alert (range.toString ());" with to make this code work with Mozilla? "

Comment: @DevelopSmith: What isn't working? Can you make a demo? The function I linked to should just replace your current `GetSelectedText()` function.

Comment: it works the problem was that I mixed both of two functions and it did the mistake. Now everything is OK and I'm very thankful of you. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 5):

```
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } 
    if (window.document.getSelection) {
        return window.document.getSelection();
    } 
    if (window.document.selection) {
        return window.document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return "";  
}
```

```
<p onmouseup="getSelectedText(); alert(txt)">
Highlight some of this text
with the mouse select press button end release
to fire the event. </p>
```

*This is my way*. You just need to select the text end alert text or anything else.
Does anyone know how OnMouse(event) set for the entire document in html, and it does not have to be directly added to html page.
 
To be on the other side, *as we can change the elements in firebug!*>-examples

Comment: heyman:
You mean that first try change element i firebag, then change it in code

Comment: @heyman:
You mean that first try change element in firebag, then change in code?
In such a manner, we know what doing better...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? My edit of the answer just improved the formatting by putting the code within a code block.

Comment: @heyman
I thought because of this sentence:
"To be on the other side, as we can change the elements in firebug!>-examples" - what mean?

Comment: @heyman you said the right thing, sorry.. Yes, I change first in firebag and then in own code!

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two problems with the above code.
-You can't be guaranteed that

```
var butn = document.getElementById("soda");
```

will work because it may execute before the document is done loading

-When you click on another element that's not a button, the selection is lost. If you change the "soda" div to  then it will work:

> ```
> <div id="diva"><b>Score</b> some <i>goals</i></div>
> <div id="soda" onclick="GetSelectedText()">This will NOT work</div>
> <input type="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()" value="This will work"/>
> ```

However I strongly recommend you look at jQuery as the others here have advised; it will make your like a *lot* easier!