# How to get selected text with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DIV field which contains some lyrics. I want to know when user is dragged & selected some part of the lyrics. How is this can be done? Example is shown below:

[image]

In this example user is dragged & selected the part which has a blue background. I want JavaScript to select "I can't believe that my sanity lies in abandoning you" part of the text. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I couldn't came up with an idea. :/

Comment: `window.getSelection()`

Comment: @vp_arth Should I use a timer for reacting when user selection is done?

Comment: you can to handle `mouseup` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this one is what you want:

```js
if (!window.x) {
  x = {};
}

x.Selector = {};
x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
  var t = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    t = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}

$('#html1').ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
    var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
    alert(mytext);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="html1">They kill me for waiting you. I can't recall a more bla bla bla bla

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0mqo0zhk/

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [How to get selected text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553534/how-to-get-selected-text-with-javascript)

This is already answered and it has worked for me as well. I've shared the answer as well as the link. Hope it helps you as well.

```
function GetSelectedText () {
if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    var range = window.getSelection ();
    alert (range.toString ());
} 
else {
    if (document.selection.createRange) { // Internet Explorer
        var range = document.selection.createRange ();
        alert (range.text);
    }
}
}

var butn = document.getElementById("soda");
butn.onclick = function(){
    GetSelectedText();
}
```

Comment: I don't care about the older versions of IE. Actually I don't care about IE itself. I want my website to work on real browsers like Chrome, Safari and other browsers that use Chromium core.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```