# calling a php script using $.POST in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, events

I have HTML form with a `textarea` and a `button` which calls the function below when a part of the text is selected. With de id of the clicked button and the selected text I want to call a php script by the `POST` method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".postbit_buttons").on("click", ".quoted_clicked", function() {
        var post = this.id;
        var selected = GetSelectedText();
        alert(" post = " + post + " seleted text = " + selected);
        $.post("test_quoted.php", {
                pid: post,
                selection: selected
            })
            .done(function() {
                alert("done")
            });
    });
});
```

Function `GetSelectedText()` to get the selection was found here.
The first alert is shown with the correct information. However, after clicking OK I get the following error message on the browser console:

> TypeError: 'collapse' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface Selection.

I have used a similar construct in another part of the forum software of which this is a part, and that works.

I have pain in my eyes of staring at this, but cannot find the cause. Is there anybody who can help me on this?

@Rory
The code of function GetSelectedText() is:

```
function GetSelectedText()
{
  var selectedText=(
        window.getSelection
        ?
            window.getSelection()
        :
            document.getSelection
            ?
                document.getSelection()
            :
                document.selection.createRange().text
     );
 if(!selectedText || selectedText=="")
 {
    if(document.activeElement.selectionStart)
    {
     selectedText = document.activeElement.value.substring(
          document.activeElement.selectionStart
          . document.activeElement.selectionEnd);
    }
 }
 return selectedText;
}
```

Thanks to Rory's question I tried things out. I discovered that is was the variable "selected" in which the selected text is stored was the cause of the error. I now use the following version of GetSelectedText():

```
function GetSelectedText () {
    if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
        var range = window.getSelection ();
        return range.toString ();
    } 
    else {
        if (document.selection.createRange) { // Internet Explorer
            var range = document.selection.createRange ();
            return range.text;
        }
    }
}
```

and it works!!
Sorry for bothering you. I do practice programming since 1968, but almost 100% was scientific computing with FORTRAN. Javascript is very new to me.

Regards, Ad Bakker

Comment: Can you please post the source of your `GetSelectedText()` function.

Comment: Where is `GetSelectedText()` function? check this: http://jsfiddle.net/L9bvU/1/ or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553534/how-to-get-selected-text-with-javascript

Comment: Somewhere you're calling `collapse` on an object that isn't a valid `Selection`, it doesn't seem to be in the posted code, so who knows where ?

Comment: In your "HTML form with a textarea and a button" you have collapsible content. I assume that the plugin (or your code) cannot use the `collapse` function because the element is not properly selected (as a jQuery object). I do not believe atm that `GetSelectedText()` or the code you have above is affecting any of that, so it's better you provide the HTML and the js plugins/code you are using for collapsing areas so people can help you.

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina. I only gave the relevant coding for the problem, the function GetSelectedText() works, because in the alert the selected text is shown.

Comment: @Armfoot. I will chech the HTML foor collapsed items. This is rather complicated, so this will take a while I fear.

Comment: function GetSelectedText()
 {
   var selectedText=(
   window.getSelection
   ?
    window.getSelection()
   :
    document.getSelection
    ?
     document.getSelection()
    :
     document.selection.createRange().text
   );
  if(!selectedText || selectedText=="")
  {
  if(document.activeElement.selectionStart)
  {
   selectedText = document.activeElement.value.substring(
     document.activeElement.selectionStart
     . document.activeElement.selectionEnd);
  }
  }
  return selectedText;
 }